# OS-uninstaller stuck on "Reinstall GRUB" after trying to remove my windows 10 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uninstall

On an HP pavillion 15u (I think). On Ubuntu 20.04, latest release I'm pretty sure

Installed OS-uninstaller after reading some of the ubuntu forum related things. I'm not sure what step of the process this program is at but I selected the Windows 10 partition I would like to delete, it gave me a pop up to confirm the choice, I hit apply, and it seemed to work fine but I believe this is taking much much longer than it should. Been going at least 25 minutes and a lot of the icons for various things like volume and powering on and off have seemingly dissapeared as well as things like the icon for google chrome.

The top left corner seems to be indicating it's running Glade2script-python3, and I read that this script was an issue when it used python2 since that was removed from Ubuntu 20.04, but that shouldnt be the case for me. Anyway I can only find issues with trying to uninstall ubuntu on the internet, anyone have any idea what's going on here exactly?

Edit: ubuntu install is kill, grub menu just takes me to a command line. Press F