# Tried to delete Windows partition, now Ubuntu won't boot and stuck on GRUB2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had Windows 10 dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and I was trying to delete the Windows partition but things went wrong.

I followed this blog from the community help page, [HowToRemoveWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows), and followed the exact same command in the same order, and then I pressed "OK" on 'OS-Uninstaller' waited for an hour but the progress bar didn't move and icons started disappearing from by Ubuntu desktop, application bar and more. I am facing something similar to this, [OS-uninstaller stuck on "Reinstall GRUB" after trying to remove my windows 10 partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300051/os-uninstaller-stuck-on-reinstall-grub-after-trying-to-remove-my-windows-10-pa).

So after an hour, I decided to reboot the system since I was not able to open any of the application on my Ubuntu and now it is booting into GRUB2.

In order to recover GRUB I tried the following steps:

1. I followed this blog, [How to Repair GRUB2 When Ubuntu Won’t Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).
   After installing "Boot Repair", I was unable to find "Recommended repair" option.
2. I followed this blog, [Grub2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing), to perform "Fix broken system".
   After following all the steps I get the following error:
   [image: grub-install error]
3. I also followed this blog ([Stuck in GRUB Rescue Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232215/stuck-in-grub-rescue-mode)) but I am not able to find `/boot/grub` on step 3. [image: grub partition list]

My Ubuntu is installed in UEFI boot mode. Before I was loading the Live installer in legacy mode and, as oldfred suggested, I then selected it in UEFI boot mode but when I followed step 1 from [How to Repair GRUB2 When Ubuntu Won’t Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/), I still can't see the option for "Recommended repair".

Is there a way I can recover my system or wiping out the entire disk and reinstalling everything is the only option for me?

Comment: I would suggest a fresh whole new install.

Comment: The How to remove Windows is for XP or old BIOS type installs. You have UEFI hardware & UEFI install of Windows. Is Ubuntu also installed in UEFI boot mode? You booted Boot-Repair/live installer in the old BIOS boot mode, that is why is wants a bios_grub partition. You must install in UEFI boot mode. Reboot in UEFI mode & then Boot-Repair should work. note that if you used Rufus it makes either a UEFI only or a BIOS only live installer. Many tools make it for both, but then you have to choose UEFI:flash as boot of flash drive.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, I even tried to Boot with the flashdrive in UEFI mode but I am still getting the same result. 
Yes, Ubuntu is also installed in UEFI boot mode. I made the flash drive using "startup disk creator".

Comment: When Ubuntu live installer is booting in UEFI mode, add Boot-Repair ppa and run the Summary report. Post the link for the report, not the report.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I managed to repair GRUB in a rather unconventional way. Since my system was always booting in GRUB, I decided to install a new copy of Ubuntu in a different partition and since Ubuntu installation also installs GRUB, I was able to get my system working. The only problem was I was not seeing my old ubuntu in the boot options, so I decided to login to the new Ubuntu and mount the old partition and recover all the files but I lost old tools which I had to install again but then again I got all the data back. 
Do you think this was a fair approach or something better could be done?